# Trouble in understanding the notion of Stability in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

**Definition:**

> Let $T: V\to V$ be a linear map on a vector space $V.$ A subspace $W$
>   of $V$ is called stable under $T$ or $T$-stable if $T(W)\subset W.$

**Problem:**

> Consider the map $T:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ sending $(x_1,x_2)$
>   to $(-x_2,x_1).$ Find all subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which are stable
>   under $T.$

**My attempt:**

There are three subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2;$ $\{0\},\mathbb{R}x,\text{ and }\mathbb{R}^2.$ It is trivial to check that $T(\{0\})\subset \{0\}$ and $T(\mathbb{R}^2)\subset \mathbb{R}^2.$ So now, we have to check that $T(\{\mathbb{R}x\})\subset \mathbb{R}x.$ But $T((x_1,x_2))=(cx_1,cx_2)=(-x_2,x_1)$ for some $c\in \mathbb{R}.$ Which implies that $(c^2+1)x_1=0$ This means that $x_1=x_2=0.$ And so in general the subspace $\mathbb{R}x$ is not stable under $T$.

I don't know whether this is correct or not and thus any feedback will be much appreciated.

Comment: There are many more polynomials than $3$!

Comment: I don't see any mistake.

Comment: I think Bernard meant to say there are many more subspaces than the 3 you listed...

Comment: Oh yeah, I meant three possible classes of subspaces. We can only have 3 possible values for dimension; 0,1 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

Your map $T$ is an anticlockwise rotation by 90 degrees, if you can relax your definition of subspace then any circle centred at the origin is stable under $T$. Further, any set of four points of the form

$$ (x_1, x_2) , (-x_2, x_1), (-x_1,-x_2), (x_2, -x_1) $$

would be stable under $T$.

Comment: None of these things are subspaces.

Comment: Yes, I should have said first that I think he is right, but the question is slightly more interesting if you consider arbitrary subsets instead.